# Text justifying issue

Tags: horizontal-alignment, hyphenation

[image]

Dear all,

I have a problem with justifying text. The last word in a sentence, for example "Keynesian" is cut into "Key-" at the end of the first sentence and "nesian" at the beginning of the following sentence.

As I send the paper for review, some reviewers do not agree with this presentation. How can I still justify the text but keep the whole word?

***Thanks for your comments. Another example to illustrate the problem. If I add some letter before "Keynesian", as you can see, the word "Keynesian" jumps to next line without being splitting.***

[image]

Comment: You can make it unbreakable by using `\mbox{Keynesian}`.

Comment: You may add `\hyphenation{keynesian}` in the document preamble.

Comment: Isn't this case sensitive? Thus \hyphenation{Keynesian}? Oxford Spelling Dictionary suggests \hyphenation{Keynes-ian} btw.

Comment: @Florian it is case insensitive.

Comment: Thank you. But I don't think it is case sensitive. "Keynesian" is just an example. As you can see on the 3th and 4th line, "insignificant" is another example. And in my paper, there are many cases like these.

Comment: there's a really extensive list of hyphenation exceptions, with additions published periodically in tugboat.  the last cumulative list can be found on ctan as [hyphenation exception log](http://mirrors.ctan.org/info/digests/tugboat/hyphenex/tb0hyf.pdf),  i've just added "in-sig-nif-i-cant", and it will appear in the next release.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you would like to disable all hyphenation in the document. Is that correct?

Comment: @ShreevatsaR I don't think it is hyphenation. It just happens at the end of the sentence. When a word is to long to fit in a line, it is splitting so that all the lines have equal length. But in Microsoft Word, the problem does not exist.

Comment: That is exactly what hyphenation means: when it is not pretty to fit a word on a line, insert a hyphen to break that word across separate lines. What else do you mean by hyphenation? Also, do you mean "end of the sentence", or end of a line?

Comment: @ShreevatsaR. oh sorry, it is the end of the line. Do you have any suggestion?

Comment: I can understand an objection to “Key-nesian” but not to “in-significant”. Hyphenation for better justification is a practice that has been in use for centuries; reviewers should concentrate on the text and not impose their disputable views on typography.

Comment: It is not reviewers place to comment on typography. Journal editors are responsible for that.

Comment: I don't see why a reviewer would waste their time since the submitted version is not generally anything like the final published version anyway. I don't mean because it gets edited, though it may, but because it gets typeset in the journal's house style. It is that style which will determine what is and isn't acceptable in terms of hyphenation and everything else. By the way, it should be 'two fold', not 'two folds', as far as I know (that is, I've never heard the plural).